# Default Spring Job BatchStatus values based on the EXITSTATUS

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am looking for default values Spring Batch Framework adds the jobs "BatchStatus" values based on the "EXITSTATUS" (Looking for defalut values framework adds).      I have tried to look some of the source code of the spring batch framework class files i didn't find.Can some one please post the class name where i can find the default logic in framework source code.

For Example When  (Simulation code )

```
              if(EXITSTATUS is FAILED)
              {
                jobs.setBatchStatus(FAILED)
              }
```

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to figure out?

Answer (score 2):

```
1. Default Exit Status is UNKNOWN and Default Status is STARTING

    (org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution)
    private volatile BatchStatus status = BatchStatus.STARTING;
    private volatile ExitStatus exitStatus = ExitStatus.UNKNOWN;

2. First time run is STARTED as

    org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob

    if (execution.getStatus() != BatchStatus.STOPPING) {
                    execution.setStartTime(new Date());
                    updateStatus(execution, BatchStatus.STARTED);

3. If your job is based on SimpleJob so
Job Status is updated based on Step Execution's Status (Note: they will apply upgrade status ) and
Job Exit Status is updated base on Step Execution's Exit Status

    org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob

        if (stepExecution != null) {
                    logger.debug("Upgrading JobExecution status: " + stepExecution);
                    execution.upgradeStatus(stepExecution.getStatus());
                    execution.setExitStatus(stepExecution.getExitStatus());
                }

4. If your job is based on FlowJob, Status and ExitStatus is updated based on the method

org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor

    public void updateJobExecutionStatus(FlowExecutionStatus status) {
            execution.setStatus(findBatchStatus(status));
            exitStatus = exitStatus.and(new ExitStatus(status.getName()));
            execution.setExitStatus(exitStatus);
        }

We are seeing Status and Exit Status are updating separately and no logic Spring set Status based on Exit Status. They are based on StepExecutionStatus or FlowExecutionStatus.
```